# Created site collection but it won't display

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been following the MS Cert Training Kit for 70-667. I went through the steps to create a web application and site collection but I can't access this site collection. I've tried various things but I have no idea how to solve this. This is what my looks like.

[image: Central Admin]

Things I've tried:

- flush dns
- add to host file
- edit registry to disable loop back checking
- edit registry to disable stricthostnamechecking
- rebooted DC, SQL and SP VM's
- added to DNS
- restarted IIS Manager Service

I have no idea what else to try now

Alternative Mapping settings
[image]

IIS Biddings 
[image]

Comment: How can't you access the site collection? Programmatically? In the browser? Are you getting an error, and if so, what error is it?

Comment: When I go through the browser, it says "the site cannot be displayed" This happens on both Chrome and IE

Comment: I tried to ping "intranet.contoso.com" but the requests timed out

Comment: You do realize that the domain "intranet.contoso.com" is fictional and that you should use an address of your own instead, don't you? Are you really reading the certification material and documentation?

Comment: Word for word http://i.imgur.com/wUETwnA.png
I tried it before with intranet.beta.com or other names. Plus the instructions go through creating a DNS entry to resolve to a certain IP so I think using "intranet.contoso.com" is what I'm suppose to do

Comment: did you use a host file, what happens if you ping the host directly with the ip instead of the hostname?

Comment: the exact same thing happens. Chrome says cannot connect and IE says Cannot display this page. I used a DNS Entry